# Hiding button for logged in users

Tags: kajabi

I would like to hide the "start free trial" button and "pricing" link for logged in users on [website](https://www.gapsquad.com/). Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated. thanks

Im not a developer but do some dabbling in code. Can this be solved using CSS? The website is built in Kajabi.